# How to populate in this kind of situation?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to draw out the data of `services` name from the `income`.

My income model is like this

```
const IncomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    shop_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Shop" },
    services: [
      {
        service_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Service" },
        price: { type: Number },
      },
    ]
    total_amount: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

As you can see I made services an array of services-id,

What I am doing now is i am write a get route for every single income.
I want to return the already populated data for services. But something wrong with my populate method.

Here is the get route.

```
router
  .route("/:income_id")
  .get((req, res) => {
      Income.findById(req.params.income_id).populate('services')
        .then((income) => {
          res.json(income);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          res.status(404).json({ msg: "Income not Found" });
        });
  });
```

Above here i try to populate the services but I am not getting the populate result.
Here is the result

```
{
    "_id": "600edf419340741fd454a391",
    "services": [
        {
            "_id": "600edf419340741fd454a392",
            "service_id": "600c5fdeef955d5794465bbd",
            "price": 4000
        },
        {
            "_id": "600edf419340741fd454a393",
            "service_id": "600c5fb6ef955d5794465bbc",
            "price": 5000
        }
    ],
    "total_amount": 9000,
    "shop_id": "600c5d505938a420fc27c90b",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-25T15:09:53.329Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-25T15:09:53.329Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: can you try `populate("services.service_id")`

Comment: @turivishal Thanks I got it. I thought the syntax inside the popuate are strings. I wonder why its working like a object